# Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have an iframe on domain A which is embedding a page from domain B. I have access to both domains. Now i want to be able to change the contents of the iframe with a script from domain A. I keep getting the `SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object` Error when i try to access the `document` property of `iframe.contentWindow`.

I tried setting the Content-Security-Policy on domain B.
I tried setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin on domain B.
I tried setting the X-Frame-Options on domain B.
I tried setting document.domain on domain B.
I even tried adding the sandbox property to the iframe on domain A.

What do i need to change in order to access the contents on the iframe? Or is this not possible at all?

I've been searching for a solution for a couple days now and cant find anything that works.

Comment: postMessage() from within the iframe, receiveMessage() from the containing page - that has worked for me.

Comment: @Yishmeray i guess thats what i'll be doing. Sad that there is no real other way of doing this.